# Best way to sanitize Input data to avoid script execution

Tags: php, laravel

#### Background Information

I'm new to Laravel community and recently I tried building a small App. During a security testing I found any input with Script element to a form actually executes that in real time.

#### Example

Following are the combination of input that I have tried so far.

- Foo (Works Correctly)
- Fooalert(1) (Throws a alert window)

```
<input type="text" name="name">
```

This is a security issue and I'm looking on possibilities to fix this. I'm sure any data before entering to database gets sanitized but issue is with HTML display.

Comment: _"I'm sure any data before entering to database gets sanitized"_ - Are you sure because you're sanitizing it or because you believe someone else is doing it for you? As far as I know, Laravel isn't sanitizing data before it's saved.

Comment: How are you outputting the data? As default, Laravel's templating engine already escapes the data when you output it. You need to explicitly tell blade not to escape it. Are you using `{{ $theVariable }}` or are you just using `echo`? This should be a non-issue if you use Laravel's features through and through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Morani suggested, best option is to use the validator and **htmlentities** function.
I had some similar use case and where I had to use a custom data array for validation. Since $this->validate will not accept any other array except $request, you may use the **Validator::make()** function.

```
//include Lib
use Validator;

//code
$validator = Validator::make()
return $validator->fails();
```

Further following might be handy with Regular use cases.

```
 $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'min:8',              // must be at least 10 characters in length
                'max:25',             // can have max 25 characters in length
                'regex:^[_A-z0-9]*((-|\s)*[_A-z0-9])*$', // must contain a special character
            ],
        ]);
```

One step ahead, you may use "htmlentities" to safely print your data in your front end page. Following snippet could be handy for you!

```
santize($data)
  {
        foreach($data as $key=>$value)
        {
            $safeinput[$key]    = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
        }

}


//usage
santize($request->input());
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

[htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php) [trim](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php) [stripslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.stripslashes.php)

Before sending a query you can just clear you value of input:

```php
function clear($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
}

clear($_POST['name']);
```

if you want to use [Laravel validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation):

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

}
```

Errors you can show on the view just using loop on `$errors`:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

or

```
@error('name')
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

Comment: Escaping data before you insert it is not necessary. You should escape it on usage/output instead. Different use cases can require different types of escaping. If you don't want the data to contain specific characters/text etc, then you should handle that using validation instead.

Comment: Thank you, i will try this out.